# Software licencing scheme

Tags: licensing, rsa, public-key-encryption

I've devised the following mechanism so as to license a software without direct connection to a server, it seems simple, yet I fail to find any serious flaw:

I plan to use asymetric crypto so as to send a message from 1 server (the licence server) to n clients (the n computers on which the software is installed)

1. The client sends (via mail, for example) some informations about the computer (MAC address, machine name, you name it)
2. On the licence server, these informations are encrypted using a well secured public (not so public) RSA key, this encrypted payload is the licence.
3. the encrypted licence is sent to the client
4. When the software is launched, it cheks for a licence file, it is able to ensure the payload was encrypted with the server key, using the corresponding RSA private key, shipped with each version of the software.
5. Once the licence decrypted, the software checks it's running on the same machine the licence was given to.

   In my opinion, no one will be able to forge an encrypted payload without access to the Licence server RSA key.

Of course, the licence might be stolen, then the software launched in a virtual machine which mimics a genuine client machine, or the software might be disassembled so as to unplug the licence check.

But is this scheme good enough, or am I utterly naive in this regard?

Thanks

Comment: Probably good enough to stop casual tampering.  There is no scheme that will be sufficient to stop serious tampering.  A protection scheme is only effective when the cost required to break it exceeds the price of a legitimate license.  Disassembling is probably the route that would be taken by someone serious about breaking your software.

Comment: Thanks, the idea is indeed to stop casual attacks. The software hasn't a broad public, and not a geek one neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a decent scheme, although are you sure you want the *client* to have the private key and the server the public key? Unless you're generating one keypair per install, shouldn't it be the other way around?

The scheme is simple, but is it practical? If your goal is to prevent casual cracking of your application there are simpler solutions that are just as effective. And if your goal is to prevent crackers from running your application, chances are that (a) you won't succeed and (b) your program isn't important enough to merit such attention.

And why would someone seek to attack the cryptography part of the license scheme when simply hex-editing the binary to change the license checking code to NOPs will almost certainly work just fine?

I'd rethink the licensing strategy and its importance to your product and its success if I were you.

Comment: My guess is that the public of the software doesn't even know what an hex editor is. Thanks for the hint, though, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Note that, at least with RSA encryption, which half of the keypair is "public" and which is "private" is simply a matter of notation -- data encrypted by one can only be decrypted by the other.  He may as well have said that the client has the public key: it's the same thing really, as long as the client doesn't have access to the other half of the keypair.

Comment: Theoretically yes. *However*, in practice, the private key is usually stored in a file that contains not just the two necessary components of the private key but several additional values that can be used to speed up cryptographic operations. And given *those* values and the private key it can be trivial to derive the public key. Look at `ssh-keygen -y` for example. There's a _good reason_ one is called 'public' and the other 'private' and users should heed that difference unless they have have the necessary depth of knowledge. And chances are most don't.

Comment: @Nik B, OK, dutifully noted. Thanks a lot for thess explanations on public/private key difference.