# Software license decryption with a public key stored in the application binary

Tags: rsa, encryption-asymmetric, license-key

With reference to the [answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696581/software-licencing-scheme?answertab=votes#tab-top) I can not understand how can the software licensing scheme works if the Private Key is kept on the license server and the public key is shipped in the application executable, and not vice verse.

I'm trying to do the following software licensing scheme:

1. User gets a Product ID (based on [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)) upon purchase and uses this inside the application to activate it.
2. The application connects to the license server which sends back encrypted text using RSA public key. This text (license) will be stored on the user's hard disk.
3. Each time the application starts it needs to decrypt this license using RSA private key, in order to extract different parameters like product edition, product limitations, registered to what company etc.

How can the application decrypt this license text if it does not have the private key but the public key?

Thanks!

EDIT:

1. If the key used to encrypt the license is available only on the server side and not to the public, can we call this a private key? In this case, if one side has the key for encryption and the other side (the public) has the key for decryption, can the side that has the key for decryption obtain the key for encryption? The concern is based on the various topics on stackoverflow that it's not that difficult to generate the public key given the private key. If you have the private key, you effectively can have both keys.
2. The idea is that once the software is activated it should no longer need to connect to the license server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The application should store its details in plain text.

When registering, the server should sign those details (including machine identification) using the private key.

Each time the application starts, it should verify that signature using the public key.

Comment: I need those details encrypted, they contain information about the limitation of application usage, like basic version, enterprise version etc. If it's in plain text the application can be unlocked by simply altering the text.

Comment: @MarcusFrenkel The server signature would not validate if the data was altered.

Comment: @MarcusFrenkel: That's what the signature is for.  If the user modifies anything, the signature would no longer match, and the user cannot re-sign it without the server's public key.

Comment: (unless the user modifies your application and puts in his own public key, or removes the check entirely)

Comment: OK now I understood. The asymmetric encryption is new to me, I though signing and encrypting is the same thing. Thank you!

Comment: @SLaks: public key can be derived from private key (http://jason4zhu.blogspot.jp/2014/10/generate-public-key-from-private-key.html) so finding private key allows re-signing the modified license and the application remains the same. :(

Comment: @Fil: Of course.  If the private key leaks, you're stuck.  That's why it's called the **private** key.

Comment: @SLaks: ops, sorry: you're right :P I commented reading the original post "Each time the application starts it needs to decrypt this license using RSA private key", so I went in misunderstanding. The application has the public key to check signature (made server side with private key). ^_^

Answer (score 3):

I don't really see the need for all this stuff.

Why not simply establish a connection to the server at validation time, have the server generate a file with all the parameters you want in it (in plain text even) and then have the server sign that file and return it to the software?

The client can read the file, and then simply validate te signature using one of the many digital signature algorithms that are out there.

Comment: I will do as you suggest. I had to accept the other answer since it came first. Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries. Good luck on getting your solution implemented and deployed.